# WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Cuando intento hacer una clausala update en java con el siguiente codigo:

```
Statement comando=null;
try {
    comando = db.conn.createStatement();
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

//System.out.println("insert into alumno(nombre,genero,estatus,activo) values("+"'"+txtNombre.getText()+"','"+charGenero+"','"+cboEstatus.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'"+",'"+charActivo+"')");
try {
    comando.executeUpdate("update menu where  set nombrePlatillo='"+txtPlatillo.getText()+"',precio='"+txtPrecio.getText()+"',descripcion='"+txtDescripcion.getText()+"' where idMenu ='"+txtidMenu.getText()+"'");
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Marca el error:

> WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Estructura :

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class BaseDeDatos {
        public static PreparedStatement prest=null;
        public static CallableStatement cllst=null;
        public static Connection conn=null;
        public static Statement st=null;
        public static ResultSet rs=null;
        public static String usuario;
        public static String password;
        public static String host;
        public static String db;
        public void Conectar(){
            try{
                usuario="root"; password=""; host="localhost"; db="restaurante?useSSL=false";
                String url="jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+db;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
            }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No es un error, es un Warning. Entiendo que no comprendes el texto del mensaje, pero ¿has intentado algo? digamos, por ejemplo, el traductor de google?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir como es la estructura general de tu cadena de conexión?

Comment: intente buscar soluciones, comprendo que es un warning pero no comprendo como es que lo soluciono.